# Intent or session mistakes?

Tags: android, session

**Question 1)** I have 2 basic user Activity who has different TAB layout.

user1:Admin
user2:Consumer

whenever I started the app, by default It redirects me to Consumer Activity'sTab with no session. Then proceed to login only redirects to either Consumer Activity's Tab or Admin Activity's Tab according to login session.

when I logged in to Admin, I was redirected to Admin Activity's Tab with Admin session. (Correct)

but when I pressed back button,

instead of redirecting to Login Layout or close the application, It redirects to Consumer Tab with Admin session (Incorrect)

how should I Fixed this? I saw some sort of FLAG? I don know how to use it. If it is needed to use xxx_FLAG, which layout should I placed the FLAG?

**Question 2)** how to destroy the session whenever user close the app by pressing back button or home button on the phone?

my current situation is when I logged in as a Member, for example "abc". when i close the app and come in again, it remains "abc" session. Unless I logged out before closing the app then it works with no more session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works for you, you may be able to get by with just keeping tight control on the backstack so you can't go back to the consumer tab once you login as an Admin.

But for your second question, overiding onBackPressed() and calling finish should achieve the result you want (whether that's recommended or not is not my place to debate)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

and as for the home button, that can't be overriden so I guess you would want to add finish() to various places that get called when the activity changes states (see the activity life cycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for exaplaining it. I got the second answer. But I do not know how to deal with 1st question. what is the backstack anyway?

Comment: @user2198192 check the link http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html